# Returning values from a linked list without moving the iterator

Tags: java, inheritance, linked-list

I have 2 classes: Student and Registry.Registry is designed to hold a list of students. When I try to return valuse of the students from the registry class, the iterator moves to the next student to get the next value hence when only 2 students are present I get a NoSuchElemennt exception.

```
public String format() 
{
    ListIterator<Student> iterator 
            = studentList.listIterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("if Statement");
        if (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println("hasNext");
            return String.format("%0s%0s%0s", 
            iterator.next().getSurName(), iterator.next().getForeName(),
            iterator.next().getStudentId());
        }

    }        

    return null;
}
```

I'd like it to return all 3 values from stud1, then move on to stud2 and so on.

<strike>Here is a link to the Student and Registry source files and a tester for both;
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ol2jyfbuyyjnrcg/1J4LlEaqc6</strike>

I will post more code if it's requested.

Since the answer is closed, no more code and the files at the link have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate around a list without using an Iterator, you should use Enhanced for loop. Then your code becomes -

```
public String format() 
{
ListIterator<Student> iterator 
        = studentList.listIterator();

for (Student student: studentList)
{
    System.out.println("For Loop");       

        return String.format("%s%s%s", 
        student.getSurName(), student.getForeName(),
        student.getStudentId());     

}   
 return null;   
}
```

Comment: I also end up with a formatConversionMismathException with this attempt at the `return String....` line

Comment: @OneGlove And that's a different error.  Not one that was part of this question, and the `String.format` that people are sending back to you is _the exact same one_ that you have in your example.  We don't know what data types you are using, but by reading on `String.format`'s javadoc page, you can easily match the % fields up with the correct data types in the `student.get...()` methods.

Comment: @One Glove My code is just a modified one of your's except I replaced Iterator with enhanced for loop. If you have a different question,please post it separately.

Comment: @EdwinBuck the error occurs when I try to use the examples posted by other people ~ I wasn't sure if it was because of something else in my code or something to do with how I was entering different code. I'll work on fixing the fixing this error then close this question afterwards.

Comment: The error was caused because of %0 which isn't allowed in the format method.

Answer (score 2):

You are advancing the iterator **every time** you call `.next()`. Call it just **once** for the current iteration.

Like so:

```
Student res = iterator.next();
return String.format("%0s%0s%0s", res.getSurName(),res.getForeName(),res.getStudentId());
```

Comment: If I enter the code as it is in my `if` block the compiler returns FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags = 0
If it's put outside the `if` statement the method will return null.

Comment: @OneGlove It should be within your `if` statement. Also, are the values being returned by the `get...()` routines, strings?

Comment: It crashes before anything gets returned; specifically line 76 in the registry class which turns out to be the return line.

Comment: ^ See the comments in the accepted answer to solve the FormatFlagsMisMatchException

Comment: +1: This is by far the simplest option.  Simply "save" the value of `iterator.next()` into a variable, and then use the variable wherever required.

Comment: Although I didn't use it for this answer; I had the same problem with a similar program, and it worked great and was far simpler that the loop I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `next` method only once, because every call forwards the cursor.

```
if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Student currStudent = iterator.next();
    //use currStudent instead of calling next
```

> I'd like it to return all 3 values from stud1, then move on to stud2 and so on.

Since your iterator is local to the method, it will be gone once the method returns. I think it will better to make your `format` method a `static` (utility) method and change it's signature to take an `Student` as a paramter. `public static String format(Student student)`. That way you can format all the students while iterating through the list.

**Update**

---

You can write a utility method as follows:

```
public static String format(Student student) {
    return String.format("%0s%0s%0s", student.getSurName(), student.getForeName(), student.getStudentId());
}
```

And for a method that can format all the students and return the formats -

```
public List<String> formatAll() {
    ListIterator<Student> iterator 
            = studentList.listIterator();
    List<String> formats = new ArrayList<String>();//to keep formats of all students
    //for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++)
    //{
        //System.out.println("if Statement");
        while (iterator.hasNext()) //while loop is better for iterators
        {
            Student currStudent = iterator.next();
            formats.add(format(student)); //calling utility method here
        }

    //}        

    return formats; // finally return the list of formats
}
```

Comment: If you want to return formats for all the students then you would have to use a collection (array, list, ...) of `String`s.

Comment: When calling the `format` method in the tester, what would I pass to make sure the method iterates through all students declared?